# Rename Document in ItemAdded

Tags: sharepoint-server, event-receivers, ssom

im trying to rename a document in the ItemAdded event receiver with the following code:

```
 public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
 {
        properties.ListItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.FileLeafRef] = properties.ListItem.ID + " " + properties.ListItem.Name;
        properties.ListItem.SystemUpdate();

        base.ItemAdded(properties);
 }
```

The code works fine when i upload a file via drag and drop but when i use the upload file dialog, Sharepoint displays the following error after clicking on OK in the dialog:

```
 [FileNotFoundException: <nativehr>0x80070002</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>]   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndFolderProperties(String bstrUrl, String bstrStartUrl, ListDocsFlags ListDocsFlags, Boolean bThrowException, Int32& phrStatus, Object& pvarFiles, Object& pvarDirs, UInt32& pdwNumberOfFiles, UInt32& pdwNumberOfDirs) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndFolderProperties(String bstrUrl, String bstrStartUrl, ListDocsFlags ListDocsFlags, Boolean bThrowException, Int32& phrStatus, Object& pvarFiles, Object& pvarDirs, UInt32& pdwNumberOfFiles, UInt32& pdwNumberOfDirs) +2415
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetFileOrFolderProperties(String strUrl, ListDocsFlags listDocsFlags, Boolean throwException, SPBasePermissions& permMask) +165
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.PropertiesCore(Boolean throwException) +95
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.get_Length() +14
   Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.ApplicationPages.UploadPage.OnSubmit(Object o, EventArgs e) +7611
   Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.ApplicationPages.UploadExPage.OnSubmit(Object o, EventArgs e) +212
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputButton.OnServerClick(EventArgs e) +134
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5062
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add full code..?

Comment: this is the full code (only without the method name):
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    properties.ListItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.FileLeafRef] = properties.ListItem.ID + " " + properties.ListItem.Name;
    properties.ListItem.SystemUpdate();

    base.ItemAdded(properties);
}